# Compare post_content with data in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am running an sync service between worpress and another website.
Before updating post_content, i try to compare my two html strings :

```
$id_post = 4;
$value= "<font color='#cc0000'>'&lt;p&gt;L&amp;#39;agence</font>";
wp_update_post(['ID' => $id_post, 'post_content' => $value]);
$the_post = get_post($id_post);
echo $the_post->post_content!= $value
```

this code return true because $the_post->post_content contains

```
<font color='#cc0000'>'&lt;p&gt;L&amp;#039;agence</font>
```

As you can see there is a difference between input & ouput string. Should i run a specific sanitize function before compare ?

Thanks for your help